# Script executed before HTML generated in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

My understanding of jQuery is the script will be executed as soon as the document is ready.

I have some dynamically generated HTML that are generated on page load as soon as response is back from server as to what to generate. The HTML are all part of a template. All of those are kicked off with the following line.

```
   window.App=new AppView;
```

and right after that line, I have

```
   alert($("#field").val());
```

where $("#field") is part of the template which was dynamically generated into HTML

And NULL was alerted.

But if I set a setTimeout to carry out the alert, I see a value.
Both lines of code are within the jQuery {}.

Can someone explain why 2nd line is executed before everything in 1st line is executed.

P.S. This is the line that generate the template

```
     $("body").html($.tmpl("temp", data));
```

Comment: That is not possible to answer without knowing the content of the AppView-function. As it might contain something that contains a timeout for instance.

Comment: There is no time out or anything related to delay in there. It's a very long code, I'll try to extract what ever relevance if necessary

Comment: @Alxandr, what else might be the reason, so I'll know what to look for. All code inside basically involve, sending GET request to server and parse the response into the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just figured out the problem. You said your code involved getting a GET request from the server? Well, that means async code. In other words, here's what happens:

```
You call new AppView
    - Inside AppView, a XHR is created, sending a GET request to server
    - Code finishes inside AppView, and returns to calling function
You call alert field val (not created yeat)
Some time later, the GET request is finnished
    - Inside callback-function for GET-request. Your field get's created.
```

Comment: Yes. That's my guess too. How is this typically solved? And there is indeed a XHR as see in the browser console

Comment: Two ways in general, one bad one (run the request synchronously), and a good one. The good one is to run your code as a callback. However, that is not something I can explain without more code.

Comment: I think I got you. Thank you.!

Answer (score 1):

You should only use jQuery when DOM is ready:

```
window.App=new AppView;

$(document).ready(function() { // Triggered when the whole DOM is ready
  alert($("#field").val());
});
```

Comment: Did he say that "both lines of code are within the jQuery {}"? Don't you think that means it's in the jQuery-function like this: `jQuery(function() {/*code here*/}`, in other word, runs on page-load?

Comment: I did say everything is within the jQuery {}. And I tried also using a separate $(document).ready..., no luck. And this time it alerts it before even the browser got a chance to display response from server

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code up in the event handler thats called when your page has finished loading!

```
$(function() {
   $('body').html($.tmpl("temp", data));
});
```